# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.closeQuietly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lucene, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to index files on S3 with Lucene and. I found this question [Integrating Lucene Index and Amazon AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817050/integrating-lucene-index-and-amazon-aws), with some code, where one can replace the FSDirectory call with

```
S3Directory dir = new S3Directory("my-lucene-index");
dir.create();
// use it in your code in place of FSDirectory, for example
dir.close();
dir.delete();
```

. In order for this to work, I needed to download some dependencies from aws, namely the following:

- aws-core-2.13.54
- utils-2.13.54
- auth-2.13.54
- http-client-spi-2.13.54
- aws-xml-protocol-2.13.54

From Lucene I have following dependencies:

- lucene-core-7.5.0
- lucene-suggest-6.4.0

For logging I have following dependencies:

- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.3
- log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3
- log4j-core-2.13.3
- log4j-api-2.13.3

Additionally I have following AWS SDK dependencies:

- aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.820

That additional AWS SDK Dependency I need for some other part of the code, however I checked by removing if that would have an influence, and it does not have an influence.

I have been checking the dependencies for several hours now, and from my understanding there should be no conflicting dependencies left in the classpath, but whenever I try to run the programm I get the error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;Lsoftware/amazon/awssdk/thirdparty/org/slf4j/Logger;)`

which apparently indicates some conflicting dependencies. But I don't see, which dependencies are conflicting. Has anyone encountered that problem? Or is there now a better approach to index data on AWS S3 with Lucene?

Comment: Looks like you're using the AWS sdk for Java version 1 (the last you listed) and 2 (the first you listed). Use one or the other, not both :)

Comment: Well I also have removed the dependency with version 1, but it didn't solve the problem actually, it was the same error message. Probably the issue is in another dependency...

Comment: Have you also gotten rid of aws-xml-protocol-2.13.54?

Comment: @micpalmia yes, same error unfortunately :(